HTML2PDF header and/or footer only on first or certain pages
The following code creates a very basic PDF from an HTML template:
$template='<page backtop="10mm" backbottom="10mm" backleft="20mm" backright="20mm">
    <page_header>
        header
    </page_header>
    <page_footer>
        footer
    </page_footer>
    <p>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br></p>
</page>';

$html2pdf=new Html2Pdf();
$html2pdf->writeHTML($template);
$html2pdf->output('test.pdf');

In this case the contents spans over 2 pages and I would like to be able to not show page_header on the second page or not show page_footer on the first. I have tried adding CSS, but this seems to be discarded:
page_header:first-child { display:none; }

This is based on this project: https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/tree/master
Edit: the following enables one to show a page_footer on the last page of the document only:
<end_last_page end_height="0">
    <page_footer>
        footer
    </page_footer>
</end_last_page>

Edit 2: adding the following to the page tag enables one to hide the header on pages 2-100 and thus show it only on the first page. Currently I haven't found a more efficient way but since I never know how many pages my document will have...
hideheader="'.implode(',', range(2,100)).'"

